# Table - alignment

Tags: tabularx

I am struggling to align the content of this table. Please, could you kindly provide some help?

[image]

```
 \begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{\textcolor{red}{Laminates devised for in-plane (tension and compression) and mode-I interlaminar fracture toughness experiments. Non-crimp fabric blankets are indicated with parenthesis. The $\$$ sign means only one veil in the symmetry plane. Explicar y poner el capitulo correspondiente. Poner bonita}}
    \label{table:notation}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l 
            >{\hsize=0.65\hsize}X % <---
            >{\hsize=0.35\hsize}X % <---
            @{}}
        \toprule
        Laminate    & Stacking sequence &          Purpose         \\ \midrule
        LTHIN\textsubscript{ILSS} & \multirow{3}{*}{$[(45\degree/0\degree)/(-45\degree/90\degree)]\textsubscript{4s}$} & Interlaminar shear strenght testing \\ \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(r){3-3}
        LTHIN\textsubscript{IP} & & Tensile and compressive testing \\ \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(r){3-3}
        LTHIN\textsubscript{LVI} & & Impact and quasi-static indentation testing \\ \midrule
        LTHIN\textsubscript{$G$\textsubscript{IC}}  & $[(45\degree/90\degree)/(-45\degree/0\degree)]\textsubscript{4s}$ & Mode-I interlaminar fracture toughness testing \\ \midrule
            LSTANDARD\textsubscript{ILSS} & \multirow{2}{*}{$[(45\degree/0\degree)/(-45\degree/90\degree)]\textsubscript{2s}$} & Interlaminar shear strenght testing \\ \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(r){3-3}
        LSTANDARD\textsubscript{LVI} & & Impact and Quasi-static indentation testing \\ \midrule
            LV1\textsubscript{IP} and LV2\textsubscript{IP} & \multirow{2}{*}{$[$(45$\degree$/V$_i$/0$\degree$)/V$_i$/($-$45$\degree$/V$_i$/90$\degree$)/V$_i$$]$\textsubscript{4$\$$} ($i$ = 1,2)} & Tensile and compressive testing \\ \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(r){3-3}
    LV1\textsubscript{LVI} and LV2\textsubscript{LVI} & & Impact and Quasi-static indentation testing \\ \midrule
            LV1\textsubscript{$G$\textsubscript{IC}} and LV2\textsubscript{$G$\textsubscript{IC}}   & $[$(45$\degree$/90$\degree$)/($-$45$\degree$/0$\degree$)/V$_i$$]$\textsubscript{6$\$$} ($i$ = 1,2) & Mode-I interlaminar fracture toughness testing \\ \bottomrule                        
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please reformat the code by using the `{}` and provide us with a complete compilable document which starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. Most likely you are looking for the `makecell` package.

Comment: A side point: you have a typo on the top right you’ll want to correct (strenght). I do that one all the time, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, 
            textfont={color=red}]{caption}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}% valid local for tis table
\centering
\caption{Laminates devised for in-plane (tension and compression) and mode-I interlaminar fracture toughness experiments. Non-crimp fabric blankets are indicated with parenthesis. The $\$$ sign means only one veil in the symmetry plane. Explicar y poner el capitulo correspondiente. Poner bonita}
\label{table:notation}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l C L @{}}
    \toprule
Laminate    & \text{Stacking sequence} &          Purpose         \\
    \midrule
LTHIN\textsubscript{ILSS} 
    & \multirow{6}{=}{\centering
                      [(\SI{45}{\degree}/%
                        \SI{0}{\degree})/%
                       (\SI{-45}{\degree}/%
                        \SI{90}{\degree})]\textsubscript{4s}}
        & Interlaminar shear strenght testing               \\ 
    \cmidrule{1-1} \cmidrule{3-3}
LTHIN\textsubscript{IP} 
    &   & Tensile and compressive testing                   \\ 
    \cmidrule{1-1} \cmidrule{3-3}
LTHIN\textsubscript{LVI} 
    &   & Impact and quasi-static indentation testing       \\ 
    \midrule
LTHIN\textsubscript{$G$\textsubscript{IC}}  
    & 
                      [(\SI{45}{\degree}/%
                        \SI{90}{\degree}/%
                       (\SI{-45}{\degree}/
                        \SI{0}{\degree})]\textsubscript{4s}
        & Mode-I interlaminar fracture toughness testing    \\ 
    \midrule
LV1\textsubscript{IP} and LV2\textsubscript{IP} 
    &   \multirow{3.4}{=}{\centering
                        [(\SI{45}{\degree}/V$_i$/\SI{0}{\degree})/ 
                          V$_i$/(\SI{-45}{\degree}/%
                          V$_i$/\SI{90}{\degree})/%
                          V$_i$]\textsubscript{4\$} ($i = 1,2$)} 
        & Tensile and compressive testing               \\ 
    \cmidrule{1-1} \cmidrule{3-3}
LV1\textsubscript{LVI} and LV2\textsubscript{LVI}
    &   & Impact and Quasi-static indentation testing   \\ 
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

table is not complete, however it show how to solve all your requirements (as i understood them). for values with units i use the `siunitx` package, and for caption the `caption` package. i also change width of columns. i suggest to have equal width of the second and third column. for long sequence, which not fit in cell i enable that it can be broken into three lines

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely get mad at me but I really think you will greatly benefit from trying to understand what math vs. text mode are good for, how simple it is to get a subscript in math mode (vs. text mode) and so on. I leave all these things untouched and focus on the `multirows`, which I replaced by `\multirowcells` that come with the `makecell` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
\def\degree{\ensuremath{{}^\circ}}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{\textcolor{red}{Laminates devised for in-plane (tension and compression) and mode-I interlaminar fracture toughness experiments. Non-crimp fabric blankets are indicated with parenthesis. The $\$$ sign means only one veil in the symmetry plane. Explicar y poner el capitulo correspondiente. Poner bonita}}
    \label{table:notation}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l 
            >{\hsize=0.65\hsize}X % <---
            >{\hsize=0.35\hsize}X % <---
            @{}}
        \toprule
        Laminate    & Stacking sequence &          Purpose         \\ \midrule
        LTHIN\textsubscript{ILSS} & 
        \multirowcell{3}[-5ex][l]{$[(45\degree/0\degree)/(-45\degree/90\degree)]\textsubscript{4s}$} 
        & Interlaminar shear strenght testing \\ \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(r){3-3}
        LTHIN\textsubscript{IP} & & Tensile and compressive testing \\ \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(r){3-3}
        LTHIN\textsubscript{LVI} & & Impact and quasi-static indentation testing \\ \midrule
        LTHIN\textsubscript{$G$\textsubscript{IC}}  & 
        \multirowcell{2}[-1ex][l]{$[(45\degree/90\degree)/(-45\degree/0\degree)]\textsubscript{4s}$}
        & Mode-I interlaminar fracture toughness testing \\ \midrule
            LSTANDARD\textsubscript{ILSS} & 
        \multirowcell{2}[-3ex][l]{$[(45\degree/0\degree)/(-45\degree/90\degree)]\textsubscript{2s}$} & Interlaminar shear strenght testing \\ \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(r){3-3}
        LSTANDARD\textsubscript{LVI} & & Impact and Quasi-static indentation testing \\ \midrule
            LV1\textsubscript{IP} and LV2\textsubscript{IP} & 
        \multirowcell{3}[-3ex][l]{$[$(45$\degree$/V$_i$/0$\degree$)/V$_i$/($-$45$\degree$/V$_i$/90$\degree$)/
        \\ \quad V$_i]$\textsubscript{4$\$$} ($i$ = 1,2)} & Tensile and compressive testing \\ \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(r){3-3}
    LV1\textsubscript{LVI} and LV2\textsubscript{LVI} & & Impact and Quasi-static indentation testing \\ \midrule
            LV1\textsubscript{$G$\textsubscript{IC}} and LV2\textsubscript{$G$\textsubscript{IC}}   & 
        \multirowcell{2}[-1ex][l]{$[$(45$\degree$/90$\degree$)/($-$45$\degree$/0$\degree$)/V$_i$$]$\textsubscript{6$\$$}
        \\ ($i$ = 1,2)} & Mode-I interlaminar fracture toughness testing \\ \bottomrule                        
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And please consider providing a complete compilable document in the future. Here I just quickly made up something crappy for `\degree` but I would like to argue that you should not use a macro of this name unless it is from the `siunitx` package.